# Automated copying of Finder comments

Tags: terminal, applescript

I have a bunch of old files in FLV format, which VLC will convert to M4V format while preserving the audio and video tracks (not re-encoding them).  Many of them have Finder comments that I want to copy to the new files, appending a note that it's converted.

I see that running:

`mdls -raw -name kMDItemFinderComment "$f"`

in bash will read the comments, but bash appears to have some trouble with non-ASCII characters.  I've tried `xattr` and an `osascript` command to apply the comment to the new file, but both are choking on the special characters (mostly bullet: `•`).

I even tinkered with making an AppleScript droplet to do it, but that's a mess too…

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
set originalFile to (path to desktop as text) & "Original.flv"
set convertedFile to (path to desktop as text) & "Converted.m4v"

set appendTextToComment to " This File Has Been Converted"

tell application "Finder"
    set originalComment to comment of alias originalFile
    set comment of alias convertedFile to originalComment & appendTextToComment
end tell
```

Obviously you need to change the file path variables to the location of your files and the appended text value to whatever you want

Comment: I'm using `on open these_items`, and repeating over the items (which are aliases), but your code was easily adapted.  Thanks.